# Benchmarking/Performance testing of the API - REST/SOAP

Tags: api, rest, soap, benchmarking

I'm trying to benchmark/ do performance testing of API's at my work. So the client facing is REST format while the backend data is retrieved by SOAP messages. So my question is can some of you share your thoughts on how you implement it (if you  have done so in the past/doing it now), am basically interested in avg response time it takes for API to return results for the client

Please let me know if you need any additional information to answer the question

Answer (score 13):

Could not say it any better than Mark, really: http://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/05/18/http_benchmark_rules

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should give JMeter a try.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can try using [Apache Benchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html).This is simple and quick
2. [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) gives you additional flexibility like adding functional cases along with performance details. Results will be almost similar to Apache Benchmark tool.
3. The detailed one which gives Functional Test Result, performance counters settings, Call response time details, CPU and Memory changes along with Load/Stress results, with different bandwidth and browser settings - [Visual Studio Team system](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/vso-cloud-load-testing-vs)

I used `VSTS2010` for performance testing. Also GET and POST are straight forward. PUT and DELETE need coded version of `webtest`.

Thanks,
Madhusudanan
Tesco

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test the REST -> SOAP calls. One more thing you can consider is to have some stubs created (for backend). This way you can perf test REST -> Stub performance followed by Stub -> SOAP perfomance. This will help in analyzing the individual components.